# How to prevent some action in app using winapi?

Tags: c++, winapi

I would like to prevent some action in my app using winapi for example I would like to block moving my window app. How can I do this?

I try this:

```
    if( pWindowsMessage->message == WM_MOVING )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(pWindowsMessage->message == WM_MOVE)
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

But it doesn't work.

Other example: How to prevent close the window?

```
    if( pWindowsMessage->message == WM_CLOSE )
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

It works. But is it a good solution?

Of course the first and the second example are in the function which get messages.

Comment: For the first one, see [WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-windowposchanging). Second one, yes, `WM_CLOSE`.

Comment: @dxiv So my solution with return 1 is not correct in every example?

Comment: Each message has its own parameters and return values, you'll need to read the docs for each.

Comment: Simple solution: Handle [WM_NCCHITTEST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nchittest), forward it to the default window procedure, and if that returns `HTCAPTION`, return `HTCLIENT` instead. That prevents the window from being moved with the mouse. It will not prevent moving the window with the keyboard, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can block messages in different areas by handling [WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nclbuttondown) messages.

And According to [WM_NCHITTEST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nchittest),we can handle events in different regions.

Here is a sample:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("hello windows");
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wndclass;
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("This program requires Windows NT!"), szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName,
        TEXT("the hello program"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN:
        if (wParam == HTCAPTION || (wParam >= HTLEFT && wParam < HTBORDER))
            return 0;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```